# touch event is not detected on Touching sprite in Cocos2dx

Tags: touch, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to obtain touch event on touching the sprite, I have been through many links and tutorials but its not working. 'm using Xcode IDE and Cocos2dx 2.1.4.
this is the method there touch event should be obtained ideally in cpp file.

```
bool ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent){

}
```

I am trying to implement touch event on a sprite. i have created sprite like this :

```
    CCSize size = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
    CCSprite *backGroundSprint = CCSprite::create("bg.jpg");
    CCSize imageSize = backGroundSprint->getContentSize();
    backGroundSprint->setScaleX(size.width/imageSize.width);
    backGroundSprint->setScaleY(size.width/imageSize.height);
    backGroundSprint->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0, 0));
    this->addChild(backGroundSprint,0);
```

i also enabled touch by doing this :

```
this->setTouchEnabled(true);
```

in

```
bool HelloWorld::init(){
```

and in my .h file i have this

public:

```
virtual void onEnter();
virtual void onExit();
virtual bool ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent);
virtual void ccTouchMoved(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent);
virtual void ccTouchEnded(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your CCLayer to obtain touches you have to do two things:

1. Call `setTouchEnabled(true)` on it.
2. Override `virtual void registerWithTouchDispatcher();`

The second method in your *.cpp file should look like this :

```
void Strona::registerWithTouchDispatcher()
{
     CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, this->getTouchPriority(), true);
}
```

Plus you also have to remember that CCSprites don't have touch capabilities, so when using this approach you will have to check if the touch occured inside the sprites bounding box (or do some other test fit for your needs).

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful..but still i need to animate an image from one place to another, if you can direct me to somewhere, where i can get help, it will be grateful.

Comment: The official forums, though a little cluttered, are quite helpfull. To hint you about simple animations : `runAction(...)` and `CCMoveTo` are the things you are looking for.

Comment: sorry to hijack, but how to detect the touch inside sprite? I used CCSprite::boundingBox() but it is incorrect for sprite inside subchildren :(

Comment: @Zennichimaro you could always post a new question :) If you want this, you have to convert the touch locations to parent space, because bounding boxes are in parent cooridante space.

Answer (score 1):

You Enable touch and register it in .cpp file

```
this->setTouchEnabled(true);
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addStandardDelegate(this, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

To check Sprite TouchEvent in Cocos2dX

```
void GameLayer::ccTouchesBegan(CCSet* touches, CCEvent* event)
{
    CCTouch* touch = (CCTouch*)( touches->anyObject() );
    CCPoint location = touch->getLocationInView();
    location = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);


    if(sprite->boundingBox().containsPoint(location))
{
    CCLog("Sprite Touched");
}
}
```